# CORS when trying to retrive refresh token from google ouath

Tags: google-api, oauth-2.0, cors

Following [https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp][1] I am trying to get user refresh token, but sending request like that:

```
    POST /o/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: accounts.google.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

code=4/v6xr77ewYqhvHSyW6UJ1w7jKwAzu&
client_id=8819981768.apps.googleusercontent.com&
client_secret={client_secret}&
redirect_uri=https://oauth2-login-demo.appspot.com/code&
grant_type=authorization_code
```

I am getting cors problem - is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Does anyone has this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Please keep in mind that refresh tokens are not intended to be used in client-side code. In particular, you disclose your client secrets this way. Refresh tokens should only be used in server-side code, where you will not be bound by the origin controls enforced by browsers.

Comment: too sad the doc doesn't say so...

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_oauth2#OAuth2_Refreshing_a_Token